# Getting the forwarded function name

Tags: c++, winapi, portable-executable

I was tried this code:

```
    HMODULE hModule = LoadLibrary(argv[1]);

    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)hModule;
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS ntHeaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((DWORD_PTR)hModule + dosHeader->e_lfanew);
    PIMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY exportDirectory = (PIMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY)((DWORD_PTR)hModule + ntHeaders->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT].VirtualAddress);

    DWORD* addressOfFunctions = (DWORD*)(hModule + exportDirectory->AddressOfFunctions);
    DWORD* addressOfNames = (DWORD*)(hModule + exportDirectory->AddressOfNames);
    WORD* addressOfNameOrdinals = (WORD*)((DWORD_PTR)hModule + exportDirectory->AddressOfNameOrdinals);
    printf("******* DLL EXPORTS *******\n");
    printf("\t%i of functions\n\t%i of names\n",(int)exportDirectory->NumberOfFunctions,(int)exportDirectory->NumberOfNames);
    printf("\tordinal\t\thint\t\tRVA\t\tattribute\t\tname\n");
    for (DWORD i = 0; i < exportDirectory->NumberOfFunctions; i++)
    {
        DWORD functionRVA = addressOfFunctions[i];
        const char* functionName = NULL;

        for (DWORD j = 0; j < exportDirectory->NumberOfNames; j++)
        {
            if (addressOfNameOrdinals[j] == i)
            {
                functionName = ((const char*)hModule + addressOfNames[j]);
                break;
            }
        }

        if (functionName != NULL)
        {
            FARPROC functionAddress = GetProcAddress(hModule, functionName);
            for (; importDescriptor->Name != 0; importDescriptor++) {
                // imported dll modules
                printf("\t%s\n", rawOffset + (importDescriptor->Name - importSection->VirtualAddress));
                thunk = importDescriptor->OriginalFirstThunk == 0 ? importDescriptor->FirstThunk : importDescriptor->OriginalFirstThunk;
                thunkData = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)(rawOffset + (thunk - importSection->VirtualAddress));

                // dll exported functions
                for (; thunkData->u1.AddressOfData != 0; thunkData++) {
                    //a cheap and probably non-reliable way of checking if the function is imported via its ordinal number ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
                    if (!(thunkData->u1.AddressOfData > 0x80000000)) {
                        char* libname1=(char*)(rawOffset + (importDescriptor->Name - importSection->VirtualAddress));
                        const char* libname=libname1;
                        char* importfunctionname1=(char*)(rawOffset + (thunkData->u1.AddressOfData - importSection->VirtualAddress + 2));
                        const char* importfunctionname=importfunctionname1;
                        HMODULE module=LoadLibrary(libname);
                        if (((DWORD)functionAddress-(DWORD)hModule)==((DWORD)GetProcAddress(module,importfunctionname)-(DWORD)module))
                            printf("\t%i\t\t%02X\t\t%0002X\t\tforwarded\t\t%s\t\t (forwarded to %s.%s)\n",  i + exportDirectory->Base,i,functionRVA,functionName,libname,importfunctionname);// (forwarded to %s.%s)
                        else
                            printf("\t%i\t\t%02X\t\t%0002X\t\tnormal\t\t%s\n",  i + exportDirectory->Base,i,functionRVA,functionName);
                    }
                    printf("\t%i\t\t%02X\t\t%0002X\t\t      \t\t%s\n",  i + exportDirectory->Base,i,functionRVA,functionName);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    FreeLibrary(hModule);
```

But it output this:

```
******* DLL EXPORTS *******
        1608 of functions
        1608 of names
        ordinal         hint            RVA             attribute               name
```

It should output this instead:

```
******* DLL EXPORTS *******
        1608 of functions
        1608 of names
        ordinal         hint            RVA             attribute               name
        4               01                              forwarded               AcquireSRWLockExclusive (forwarded to NTDLL.RtlAcquireSRWLockExclusive)
```

What I'm doing wrong and how can I get the forwarded function name?

P/S: My compiler was MinGW (installed on Windows).

Comment: If this is compiled for a 64-bit target, the code truncates addresses all over the place. Things like `(DWORD)functionAddress` will do exactly what you wrote, which possibly does not coincide with what you meant.

Comment: *how can I get the forwarded function name* unclear at all, what you trying todo. unclear your question. the code is terrible

Comment: When determining the values for `addressOfFunctions` and `addressOfNames`, you are not casting `hModule` to `DWORD_PTR` before performing arithmetic on it, like you do with your other uses of `hModule`, so you are performing pointer arithmetic instead of integer arithmetic, using the wrong pointer type.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I did use it to be detecting the forwarded functions and it did works without that modifies.

Answer (score 0):

```
void DumpExport(PVOID hmod)
{
    ULONG size;
    if (PIMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY pied = (PIMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY)RtlImageDirectoryEntryToData(hmod, TRUE, IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT, &size))
    {
        if (DWORD NumberOfFunctions = pied->NumberOfFunctions)
        {
            DbgPrint("NumberOfFunctions=%u\r\n", NumberOfFunctions);
            if (PLONG bits = (PLONG)LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED|LMEM_ZEROINIT, (NumberOfFunctions + 7) >> 3))
            {
                ULONG i;
                PULONG AddressOfFunctions = (PULONG)RtlOffsetToPointer(hmod, pied->AddressOfFunctions);
                if (DWORD NumberOfNames = pied->NumberOfNames)
                {
                    DbgPrint("NumberOfNames=%u\r\n", NumberOfNames);

                    PULONG AddressOfNames = (PULONG)RtlOffsetToPointer(hmod, pied->AddressOfNames);
                    PUSHORT AddressOfNameOrdinals = (PUSHORT)RtlOffsetToPointer(hmod, pied->AddressOfNameOrdinals);
                    do 
                    {
                        PCSTR Name = RtlOffsetToPointer(hmod, *AddressOfNames++);
                        
                        _bittestandset(bits, i = *AddressOfNameOrdinals++);
                        
                        PVOID pv = RtlOffsetToPointer(hmod, AddressOfFunctions[i]);

                        if ((ULONG_PTR)pv - (ULONG_PTR)pied < size)
                        {
                            DbgPrint("%s -> %s\r\n", Name, pv);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            DbgPrint("%08X %s\r\n", RtlPointerToOffset(hmod, pv), Name);
                        }
                    } while (--NumberOfNames);
                }

                DWORD Base = pied->Base;
                AddressOfFunctions += NumberOfFunctions;
                do 
                {
                    --AddressOfFunctions;
                    if (!_bittestandset(bits, --NumberOfFunctions))
                    {
                        PVOID pv = RtlOffsetToPointer(hmod, *AddressOfFunctions);

                        if ((ULONG_PTR)pv - (ULONG_PTR)pied < size)
                        {
                            DbgPrint("#%u -> %s\r\n", Base + NumberOfFunctions, pv);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            DbgPrint("%08X #%u\r\n", RtlPointerToOffset(hmod, pv), Base + NumberOfFunctions);
                        }
                    }
                } while (NumberOfFunctions);
                LocalFree(bits);
            }
        }
    }
}

void DumpExport(PCWSTR pszLibName)
{
    if (HMODULE hmod = LoadLibraryExW(pszLibName, 0, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE))
    {
        __try {
            DumpExport(PAGE_ALIGN(hmod));
        }
        __except(EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER){
        }
        FreeLibrary(hmod);
    }
}
```

Comment: A compiler error I was encountered looks like this: "_bittestandset doesn't declared"
What function should I write as a replacement?

Comment: @winapiadmin if you simply search in google, you can find [`_bittestandset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/bittestandset-bittestandset64?view=msvc-170) - and *Header file <intrin.h>* - so you need `#include <intrin.h>`

Comment: Yes but it can't include in my code before I was comment., and the `RtlOffsetToPointer` is the Windows Drivers function. What replacement should I write (simple)?

Comment: @winapiadmin again - `RtlOffsetToPointer` not a **function**. this is **macro** - in what problem use it definition ?! `#define RtlOffsetToPointer(B,O)  ((PCHAR)( ((PCHAR)(B)) + ((ULONG_PTR)(O))  ))` or use another analog. in what problem `#include <intrin.h>` ? or just copy/paste `unsigned char _bittestandset(long *, long)` ? this is compiler instrinsic. in any case all this not related to your question at all. this is for very basic knowledge or language and common logic

Comment: After changing, the undefined reference...C:\Users\asdfs\AppData\Local\Temp\ccbMmHlw.o: In function `Z10DumpExportPv':
C:\Users\asdfs\OneDrive\pedumper\example/main.cpp:162: undefined reference to `_bittestandset(long*, long)'
C:\Users\asdfs\OneDrive\pedumper\example/main.cpp:182: undefined reference to `_bittestandset(long*, long)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @winapiadmin - are you read link ? This is CL compiler intrinsic. Implemented by compliler. You use another compiler. As result and this error. You can not solve task how set bit ?

Comment: Now it crashed.... without compiler and runtime errors, looks like access violation....

Comment: @winapiadmin - my code is correct. if it crashed, this is your error. and not need *look like* you mast able by seld detect exactly place and reason

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255714/discussion-between-winapiadmin-and-rbmm).

Comment: @RbMm You should probably add some explanation about your code. Like what changes did you make in OP's code etc or what is the problem with OP's code.

Comment: @user12002570 i not did any changes to OP code. My code is absolutely different. I don't know what to comment here. Code say for self. Simply dump exported function, by names and by ordinals, for noname export. Dump export with RVA and forward with dll.name . If you have concrete questions, maybe can give more concrete answers

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the pointer arithmetic, it should integer arithmetic.

A code which prints the forwarded function name in C:

```
HMODULE hModule = LoadLibrary(argv[1]);

PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)hModule;
PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS ntHeaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((DWORD_PTR)hModule + dosHeader->e_lfanew);
PIMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY exportDirectory = (PIMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY)((DWORD_PTR)hModule + ntHeaders->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT].VirtualAddress);

DWORD* addressOfFunctions = (DWORD*)((DWORD)hModule + exportDirectory->AddressOfFunctions);
DWORD* addressOfNames = (DWORD*)((DWORD)hModule + exportDirectory->AddressOfNames);
WORD* addressOfNameOrdinals = (WORD*)((DWORD)hModule + exportDirectory->AddressOfNameOrdinals);
for (DWORD i = 0; i < exportDirectory->NumberOfFunctions; i++)
{
    DWORD functionRVA = addressOfFunctions[i];
    const char* functionName = "";

    for (DWORD j = 0; j < exportDirectory->NumberOfNames; j++)
    {
        if (addressOfNameOrdinals[j] == i)
        {
            functionName = (const char*)((DWORD)hModule + addressOfNames[j]);
            break;
        }
    }

FARPROC functionAddress = GetProcAddress(hModule, functionName);
DWORD dwEATStart = ntHeaders->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT].VirtualAddress;
DWORD dwEATEnd = dwEATStart + ntHeaders->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT].Size;
if (dwEATStart<((DWORD_PTR)functionAddress-0)<dwEATEnd)
    printf("\tforwarded\t%s (forwarded to %s)\n",  functionName,(DWORD_PTR)hModule+functionRVA);
else
    printf("\tnormal\t\t%s\n", functionName);
}

FreeLibrary(hModule);
```

The thing needed to do is preventing the non-forwarded functions to be interpreted as forwarded functions.